# Issue with running dart/flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Whenever I type flutter on the flutter console a message saying:

```
Error: 'pub upgrade' still failing after 10 tries, giving up.
This version of C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Developemtn\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information and then contact the software publisher."
```

Comes up, how can I fix this?

Comment: Can you add information about your system?

Answer (score 0):

Your OS should be Windows 7 SP1 or later(64-bit) and available disk space should be 400 MB. Flutter also depends on PowerShell 5.0 or newer Git for windows being available in your environment.